# On the gap of Jensen's inequality

Tags: reference-request, jensen-inequality

Say $X$ is a bounded random variable with mean $0$,
and $f$ is a convex function with $f(0)=0$.
Then the usual Jensen's inequality states
$$0≤\mathbb Ef(X).$$
Nothing special.
However, if I add the condition that $\mathbb P\{X≥a\}≥b$
for some positive $a,b$, then the equality cannot hold.
And I claim that
$$0<bf(a)+(1-b)f(-ab/(1-b))≤\mathbb Ef(X).$$
In other words, I claim that the *worst case scenario*
is when all masses concentrate on $a$ and on $-ab/(1-b)$.
(The number $-ab/(1-b)$ is such that the mean is still $0$.)

**Question:** Is it (trivially) true?
If so, is there a name or something I can cite?